# How to pull from one remote and push to another overriding the author as myself?

Tags: git

I already have a working git repository with 2 remotes (say A and B).

I want to pull changes from remote A and push them to B but overriding the author as myself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can think of is first checking out code from first repo, do changes that require, update remote url to point repo B and push to remote.

1. Pull the source workspace
   `git clone https://github.com/username/a.git`
2. Do changes, add them to staging area and commit
   `git add .`
   `git commit -m "your message"`
3. Update remote url to point new repository and then push it
   `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/b.git`
   `git push origin master`

Comment: Alternatively we can also clean (`git clean`) local workspace after cloning from repo A and then add new remote URL (`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/b.git`) and push changes to remote.